# Composer not installing dependencies of dependencies

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I have made composer packages (as zip files) and a repository using satis.
This the repository definition for satis:

```
{
"name": "vendor_initial_repo",
"repositories": [
    {   
        "type": "package", 
        "package": { "name": "vendor/core-bundle", "version": "dev-master", "dist": { "url": "http://vendor.com/bundles/vendor_core_bundle.zip", "type": "zip" } }
    },
    {   
        "type": "package", 
        "package": { "name": "vendor/security-bundle", "version": "dev-master", "dist":     { "url": "http://vendor.com/bundles/vendor_security_bundle.zip", "type": "zip" } }
    }
}
```

---

composer.json for core-bundle:

```
{
"name": "vendor/core-bundle",
"description": "Bundle containing all other vendor Bundles and more",
"keywords": ["Symfony"],
"type": "symfony-bundle",
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.2",
    "symfony/symfony": ">=2.3.0",
    "vendor/security-bundle": "dev-master",
    "braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle": "2.1.*@dev",
    "bower-asset/jquery": "1.11.*",
    "bower-asset/jquery-ui": "1.11.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": { "Tezlabs\\CoreBundle\\": "" }
},
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "1.0-dev"
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "web/resources/vendor",
        "bower-asset-library": "web/resources/vendor"
    }
}
}
```

---

I was able to install the core-bundle by adding it to the "require" key of the composer.json of the application. I also set "minimum-stability" to "dev" there.then I installed core-bundle using `composer --dev --prefer-dist --with-dependencies vendor/core-bundle` which worked however it did not install "vendor/security-bundle" or any of "core-bundle"'s dependencies.What is the Problem?
I also tried this using `composer install`: same result

Comment: It looks like the problem is with packaging the files as zip.It works when I use vcs packages.However in the "include" files generated by satis for zip packages there are no keys like "require".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the "package" type, you have to provide ALL information that is needed for Composer operation within it.

That "package" type is meant as a replacement for software that does not provide a "composer.json" file, where you are unable to fix this fact yourself (e.g. someone else abandoned it somewhere).

Composer is best used with repositories as the source of the software. That way the "composer.json" file inside that repository will get evaluated, together with branch names and tags existing in that repository. This is the easiest way to be successful with Composer.

If you want to create ZIP packages from these versions, you can configure Satis to do this, you don't have to do it yourself - see the ["archive" option for Satis](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md#downloads).